# String Format in xaml

Tags: silverlight-4.0, string-formatting

I have read so many blogs and find out we cna use stringFormat property in xaml to format the binded value without using converter.

I want to use the same thing,but dont know how is it possible in my case.

Like my string is Abc$% now using string format i want the result only Abc.

How can I use stringFormat in xaml so i can Got my desired result.

Thanks
Hardik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that using stringFormat. The stringFormat only allows you to decorate strings not manipulate them.

stringFormat works exactly like String.Format(...);

If you'd like to manipulate text in XAML, then you can try to create an IValueConverter class that chops off the text.